# XSLT Wrap Every nth Item in a New Container

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

So I've written basic XSLT in the past, but I ran into a new issue.

We're working with a grid system and as a consequence to that, a simple `for-each` won't suffice. Instead, I need to create a new `row` in my HTML output every 3 items.

**In short**, I need help writing XSLT (from scratch) so that this happens:

The Idea:

```
<!-- The below div ("group") should repeat every group -->
<div class="group">
  <h2>Group #</h2>
  <!-- The below div ("row") should repeat every 3 items -->
  <div class="row">
    <!-- The below div ("four columns") should be repeated every item -->
    <div class="four columns">
      <div class="item">...</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The XML:

```
<group name="Group 1">
  <item name="Item 1" />
  <item name="Item 2" />
  <item name="Item 3" />
  <item name="Item 4" />
</group>

<group name="Group 2">
  ...
</group>
```

What it should look output:

```
<div class="group">
  <h2>Group 1</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="four columns">
      <div class="item">Item 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="four columns">
      <div class="item">Item 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="four columns">
      <div class="item">Item 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">  
    <div class="four columns">
      <div class="item">Item 4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="group">
  <h2>Group 2</h2>
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: You didn't write what's the problem. Show us your code (some XSLT) what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks @TOUDIdel , I clarified a bit more in the intro. I hope my issue is clear now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you had a parameter for the number of rows you wished to group, you would start off by selecting the **item** elements with the current **group** element, that were in the 1st, 4th, 7th, etc, position.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="item[position() mod $rows = 1]" mode="group"/>
```

(Note the use of mode, as you will have two templates matching **item** elements)

Then, within the template that matched this, you would select all the items within the group like so

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="self::*|following-sibling::item[position() &lt; $rows]"/>
```

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:param name="rows" select="3"/>

   <xsl:template match="group">
      <div class="group">
         <h2><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></h2>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="item[position() mod $rows = 1]" mode="group"/>
      </div>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="item" mode="group">
      <div class="row">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="self::*|following-sibling::item[position() &lt; $rows]"/>
      </div>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="item">
      <div class="four columns">
         <div class="item"><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></div>
      </div>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied on the following XML

```
<groups>
    <group name="Group 1">
        <item name="Item 1"/>
        <item name="Item 2"/>
        <item name="Item 3"/>
        <item name="Item 4"/>
    </group>
    <group name="Group 2">
        <item name="Item 1"/>
        <item name="Item 2"/>
        <item name="Item 3"/>
        <item name="Item 4"/>
    </group>
</groups>
```

The following is output

```
<a>
   <div class="group">
      <h2>Group 1</h2>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="four columns">
            <div class="item">Item 1</div>
         </div>
         <div class="four columns">
            <div class="item">Item 2</div>
         </div>
         <div class="four columns">
            <div class="item">Item 3</div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="four columns">
            <div class="item">Item 4</div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="group">
      <h2>Group 2</h2>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="four columns">
            <div class="item">Item 1</div>
         </div>
         <div class="four columns">
            <div class="item">Item 2</div>
         </div>
         <div class="four columns">
            <div class="item">Item 3</div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="four columns">
            <div class="item">Item 4</div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</a>
```

EDIT: In answer to your comment, if you wanted to alter the class name of the last column if there are not an exact number of columns, you could do this with an **xsl:choose** to check if it was the last item, and it's position did not match the required number.

```
<xsl:template match="item">
   <div>
      <xsl:attribute name="class">
         <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="not(following-sibling::item) and position() mod $rows != 0">end</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>four columns</xsl:otherwise>
         </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <div class="item">
         <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
      </div>
   </div>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Absolutely amazing! You've answered the question wonderfully! :) I do have one last question that wasn't part of the original question. In my example, every row must have a total of twelve columns. If a row doesn't add up to twelve columns, the last column must have the class `end` applied to it (so in the above example, Item 4's parent div would have the `end` class.) Any idea on how to add that functionality?

Comment: I'm added a bit on to my question to hopefully explain. Hope it helps!

Comment: just had to readjust the syntax to my data source and it worked in less than five minutes! thanks!